# How can I convert all percentages into decimals, and write that to CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping

The objective is to convert all of the values from percentages to decimal form. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


FIU = open('C://Users//joey//Desktop//response.txt','r').read()
#soup = BeautifulSoup(FIU, "html.parser")


soup = BeautifulSoup(FIU, "lxml")

tables = soup.find_all('table')

for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        if len(cells) == 7:  # this filters out rows with 'Term', 'Instructor Name' etc.
            for cell in cells:
                print(cell.text + "\t", end="")  # \t is a Tab character, and end="" prevents a newline between cells
            print("")  # newline after each row



def p2f(x): return float(x.strip('%'))/100
percentage_list = []
for cell in cells:
    if '%' in cell.text:
        percentage_list.append(p2f(cell.text))
```

At the very bottom, you'll see the function I tried to strip the percentages and then divide by 100 to get a decimal for every number. However, it didn't affect the output:

```
Description of course objectives and assignments    0.0%    68.4%   10.5%   15.8%   5.3%    0.0%    
Communication of ideas and information  0.0%    52.6%   26.3%   10.5%   10.5%   0.0%    
Expression of expectations for performance in this class    0.0%    68.4%   15.8%   10.5%   0.0%    5.3%    
Availability to assist students in or out of class  0.0%    57.9%   31.6%   10.5%   0.0%    0.0%    
Respect and concern for students    0.0%    47.4%   42.1%   10.5%   0.0%    0.0%    
Stimulation of interest in course   0.0%    47.4%   26.3%   21.1%   0.0%    5.3%    
Facilitation of learning    0.0%    52.6%   26.3%   10.5%   10.5%   0.0%    
Overall assessment of instructor    0.0%    52.6%   31.6%   10.5%   0.0%    5.3%
```

What code can I implement to solve this problem?

Comment: can you print the percentage_list?

Comment: @flamelite I updated my post so it has the output, if that's what you meant? The code itself already 'prints' it to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Use your p2f function as here:

```
def p2f(x): 
    return float(x.strip('%'))/100    
for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        if len(cells) == 7:
            for cell in cells:
                if '%' in cell.text:
                    print(str(p2f(cell.text)) + "\t", end="")
                else:
                    print(cell.text + "\t", end="")
                print("")  # newline after each row
```

Comment: This didn't work as intended. https://imgur.com/a/2u5wd
Not sure what the issue is, but it simply removed all numbers, and left a small block afterwards.

Comment: see the error in your debug report: NameError: name 'p2f' is not defined.

Comment: Define your p2f function very first then call it below.

Comment: Ah oops. Forgot that. It was commented out up above. I brought it back in, and now I have a type error: https://imgur.com/a/p0niA
No undefined function error, but a type error, and still empty output.

Comment: Again see the error that is telling you that you can not add a float type data and string. So you need to type cast the float type data to string type data.

Comment: I've been programming in Python for a couple months now. I know the basics. I literally just used the code you gave me and received that error. I've never had that error before. I fail to see how this is a result of me not knowing the basics when all I did was use your code. I have no idea how to typecast code that I myself didn't even create. I'm confused by this.

Comment: Don't be confused the mistake was mine :). All i did was i figured out root cause of your problem and without testing the code on my machine i posted in as answer. But what i meant from my above comment is that you can see the error clearly in the debug report.

Comment: So what exactly is your code doing that results in an error? Converting from string to float?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158167/discussion-between-flamelite-and-j-sowwy).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to convert it into a dictionary, but it didn't come out as clean as I hoped

```
 one_table = {}
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    name = cells[0].text
    one_table[name] = []
    if all('%' in cell.text for cell in cells[1:]):
        one_table[name] = [] #Create dictionary entry if this is a percentage row
    else:
        continue  #Otherwise, move on to the next row
    for cell in cells[1:]:
            one_table[name].append(p2f(cell.text))


with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in one_table.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])

print(one_table)
```

The result was:

```
{'Term: 1171 - Spring 2017': [], 'Instructor Name: Austin, Lathan Craig': [], 'Course: TRA   4721  ': [], 'Enrolled: 27': [], '\xa0': [], 'Question': [], 'Description of course objectives and assignments': [0.0, 0.684, 0.105, 0.158, 0.053, 0.0], 'Communication of ideas and information': [0.0, 0.526, 0.263, 0.105, 0.105, 0.0], 'Expression of expectations for performance in this class': [0.0, 0.684, 0.158, 0.105, 0.0, 0.053], 'Availability to assist students in or out of class': [0.0, 0.579, 0.316, 0.105, 0.0, 0.0], 'Respect and concern for students': [0.0, 0.474, 0.42100000000000004, 0.105, 0.0, 0.0], 'Stimulation of interest in course': [0.0, 0.474, 0.263, 0.21100000000000002, 0.0, 0.053], 'Facilitation of learning': [0.0, 0.526, 0.263, 0.105, 0.105, 0.0], 'Overall assessment of instructor': [0.0, 0.526, 0.316, 0.105, 0.0, 0.053]}
```

So it did write to a CSV, but I somehow lost 99% of the data in converting it to the dictionary. There's only one table, where I had hundreds before. The output in CSV is also less than ideal:

[image: Not ideal]

So if I can somehow find a way to include *all of my data*, and then comma separate it like it is supposed to, then perhaps this could be sufficient.